# Unable to run java file

Tags: software-installation, java

I have created a Java program:

```
public class Hello{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("HEllo world");
}
}
```

My /etc/environment file looks like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/$JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java" "
```

My java program gets compiled perfectly.

```
nehal@nehal-Inspiron-5559:~/Desktop$ javac Hello.java 
nehal@nehal-Inspiron-5559:~/Desktop$ java Hello
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello
```

When I run it it gives me this error.
The path where my java is installed:

```
/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin
```

How can resolve this issue?
P.S. Initially i had open-jdk installed,but i removed it completely and installed Oracle Java8

**Edit:**
The above problem is still unsolved but my code runs when I run it like:

```
java -cp . Hello
```

Comment: Just to test, can you do: `cd ~/Documents && gedit Hello.java` then, copy your code to this file, then `javac Hello.java && java Hello`

Comment: @Raphael Same error

Comment: Please post the output of `echo $JAVA_PATH`

Comment: @George `nehal@nehal-Inspiron-5559:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

Comment: What of `echo $PATH | grep -i java`?

Comment: @George `echo $PATH | grep -i java
/home/nehal/bin:/home/nehal/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/$JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java" " :/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin`

Comment: I don't think this is right `/$JAVA_HOME=‌​"/usr/lib/java/jdk1.‌​8.0_131/bin/java" " `

Comment: Make sure your the java `file name` is the same as the `java class` example java name ==> Hello.java, class name => Hello

Answer (score 0):

Please change:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/$JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java" "
```

To:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" 

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131"
```

Then `source` the `/etc/environment` with `source /etc/enviroment`.

Now run `echo $JAVA_PATH`

Comment: My /etc/environment was previously:  `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" `

`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131"` I changed it to the new path

Comment: What does this mean? ->Then source the /etc/environment with source /etc/enviroment

Comment: It simply means to reload that file so your environmental settings can be picked up after the changes

Comment: You missed an `n` in the spelling of `environment`

Comment: can you create a chat room?

Comment: let me try aas I have not used that before

Comment: yeah,sorry for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62265/discussion-between-george-and-nrb).